# How do I get my videos off my iPad 2?

Tags: windows, ipad

I put a bunch of videos onto my iPad 2 a while ago, syncing them over iTunes. The PC that I set this up on is no longer available. All I have now is my iPad with the videos, and a new computer with a clean install of iTunes.

Now it seems that iTunes wants to wipe all those videos off the iPad in order to set up a sync.

Can I get these videos off the iPad somehow?

(connecting the iPad as a camera doesn't help: this only shows videos shot using the iPad camera, but not the videos I recorded with my camcorder and synced over iTunes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into software like [TouchCopy](http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/index.php) to transfer the videos? It offers a Windows and Mac version. I prefer [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to this software on a Mac, but you have tagged this windows so TouchCopy seems a better fit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Is there any way to do this for free? (I know... I'm just too used to file copying not requiring pay-for software...)

Comment: I certainly would have recommended a free solution if such existed. I've seen many malware scams over the long haul advertising this such capability - so please be secure and a bit skeptical when downloading any software. :-) Best of luck. This developer does offer a free preview - so it's more up to you which costs less - getting another copy of the video or paying for the software.

Comment: We ended up doing it the hard way. FWIW, the owner of the said iPad has moved to Android, in no small part due to issues just like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the update - it's a good thing that people can choose which ecosystem works better for them.